# Minecraft head Genration

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

[This thread](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/redstone-discussion-and/2409218-1-8-4-custom-non-player-head-help) describes how to make custom heads using the URL to the skin file stored [minecraft.net](https://minecraft.net/en/), but it assumes that you know the URL ahead of time. How can I find that URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an in-game solution, you can use `/give` to provide yourself with the most up-to-date skin file like so, which will be changed into the base64-encoded JSON object containing the URL:

```
/give @p minecraft:skull 1 3 {SkullOwner:"Skylinerw"}
```

And then you can throw the item on the ground, place a command block close to it, and then run the following command in the command block:

```
/entitydata @e[type=Item,c=1] {}
```

The Last Output box in the command block will then look something similar to the following (though excess tags have been removed for the example):

```
[16:45:14] The data tag did not change: {Item:{id:"minecraft:skull",Count:1b,tag:{SkullOwner:{Id:"b9aa57fe-649e-4d48-806e-63af2faff5c6",Properties:{textures:[0:{Value:"eyJ0aW1lc3RhbXAiOjE0Nzk1OTE4OTMxNDIsInByb2ZpbGVJZCI6ImI5YWE1N2ZlNjQ5ZTRkNDg4MDZlNjNhZjJmYWZmNWM2IiwicHJvZmlsZU5hbWUiOiJTa3lsaW5lcnciLCJzaWduYXR1cmVSZXF1aXJlZCI6dHJ1ZSwidGV4dHVyZXMiOnsiU0tJTiI6eyJ1cmwiOiJodHRwOi8vdGV4dHVyZXMubWluZWNyYWZ0Lm5ldC90ZXh0dXJlLzRlOWUxMmQ0ZWY4N2I0ZTljMTAyYjIwNDA4Y2FlZjVhNDlkN2M2NjM3NTk0OWIwMTU5Y2Y5NDE2ZGQxYjhhZiJ9fX0="}]},Name:"Skylinerw"}},Damage:3s}}
```

The `Value` string tag contains the base64-encoded object that you'll need. You can decode it using any decoder, such as [this one](https://www.base64decode.org/). The decoded object will look like:

```
{"timestamp":1479591893142,"profileId":"b9aa57fe649e4d48806e63af2faff5c6","profileName":"Skylinerw","signatureRequired":true,"textures":{"SKIN":{"url":"http://textures.minecraft.net/texture/4e9e12d4ef87b4e9c102b20408caef5a49d7c66375949b0159cf9416dd1b8af"}}}
```

The `url` string will be the link to the skin file, being the most current skin file using this method. Changing your skin will create a new URL for that skin file, so you would have to repeat this process each time you change your skin.